# Netbeans jPanel build successful but no Output

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

Every time I run this, it shows Build Successful. But no output is shown. I've tried configuring the project's main class, but didn't work. Is there anything to recheck in this code? I've pasted the whole code btw.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import static sun.management.snmp.jvminstr.JvmThreadInstanceEntryImpl.ThreadStateMap.Byte0.runnable;
    public class loginPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public loginPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jEmailField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jPasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        showPassword = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jSignIn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jRegister = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1Label3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1Label2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1Label1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(36, 47, 65));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 153));
        jLabel1.setText("Login");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Email");

        jEmailField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(36, 47, 65));
        jEmailField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jEmailField.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jEmailField.setText("Enter Your Email");
        jEmailField.setToolTipText("");
        jEmailField.setBorder(null);

        jLabel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(36, 47, 65));
        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("Password");

        jPasswordField.setEditable(false);
        jPasswordField.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(36, 47, 65));
        jPasswordField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jPasswordField.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jPasswordField.setText("dsfsdfdsfsdfsdfsf");
        jPasswordField.setBorder(null);

        showPassword.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(36, 47, 65));
        showPassword.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        showPassword.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        showPassword.setText("Show Password");
        showPassword.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                showPasswordActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jSignIn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 102));
        jSignIn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jSignIn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jSignIn.setText("Sign In");
        jSignIn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jSignInActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRegister.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 102));
        jRegister.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jRegister.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jRegister.setText("Register");
        jRegister.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRegisterActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));
        jButton3.setText("Forgot Password");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(172, 172, 172)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(jEmailField)
                                .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                                .addComponent(jPasswordField)
                                .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 328, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 326, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jSignIn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                                        .addComponent(jRegister))))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(114, 114, 114)
                                .addComponent(showPassword)
                                .addGap(117, 117, 117)))))
                .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(183, 183, 183))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jEmailField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(showPassword)
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jRegister)
                    .addComponent(jSignIn))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addContainerGap(64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        add(jPanel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 0, 500, 670));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 153));
        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        jPanel1Label3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jPanel1Label3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 51));
        jPanel1Label3.setText("Chase Your Dream");
        jPanel1Label3.setToolTipText("");
        jPanel1.add(jPanel1Label3);
        jPanel1Label3.setBounds(160, 530, 200, 60);

        jPanel1Label2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1Label2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Roy\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\login_form_1\\roy-hill.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jPanel1Label2);
        jPanel1Label2.setBounds(90, 200, 300, 260);

        jPanel1Label1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monotype Corsiva", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        jPanel1Label1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 153));
        jPanel1Label1.setText("Login Panel 1");
        jPanel1.add(jPanel1Label1);
        jPanel1Label1.setBounds(120, 120, 300, 50);

        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Roy\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\login_form_1\\Spiral.png")); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("jLabel4");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4);
        jLabel4.setBounds(260, 0, 310, 670);

        jLabel8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Roy\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\login_form_1\\Mac01.jpg")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jLabel8);
        jLabel8.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 670);

        add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 530, 670));
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    //Show or Hide Password Operation:
    private void showPasswordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        if(showPassword.isSelected()){
            jPasswordField.setEchoChar((char)0);
        }else{
          jPasswordField.setEchoChar('*');
        }
    }                                            

    private void jRegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    }                                         


    private void jSignInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       


    public static void main(String [] args){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new loginPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void jSignInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        }
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jEmailField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jPanel1Label1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jPanel1Label2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jPanel1Label3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField;
    private javax.swing.JButton jRegister;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jSignIn;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox showPassword;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Finally done with this problem. (Tried so many ways)

Just replaced this line:

> public class loginPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel

with this:

> public class loginPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame

Answer (score 1):

All components need to be, eventually, added to a top level container (ie a `JFrame`) before they can be shown on the screen

Have a look at [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for more details

Answer (score -1):

In the main class you have to call your frame.

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {       
        new loginpanel().setVisible(true);
    }
```